# jQuery Mobile - Page jumps to top before transition

Tags: jquery, mobile, jquery-mobile

Anyone had this issue where the page quickly jumps to the top before a transition (leaving the fixed-position header looking lost halfway down the page)?

On returning to the page, the page ends up at the top, but since I'm dealing with a long list, it would be preferable to have it stay where I left off on the previous page.

I'm using in-page divs instead of actual separate pages, if that's perhaps contributing to it.

Any tips appreciated!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use $.mobile.defaultHomeScroll = 0.

From here: https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/issues/2846

Comment: I'm experiencing the exact same problem as OP, but this didn't solve it for me. Any thoughts?

Comment: Important Note: You have to do this *after* mobileinit fires, unlike some other $.mobile.* variables.

Comment: This works for returning to the same position, but I still get the visible page jump before page transition.

Comment: Same here. This bug (which it is from end-user point of view) has prevented me from using jQuery Mobile over the years. It has never been solved.

Comment: Worked for me, keep in mind, You can disable this behavior if you like by setting $.mobile.defaultHomeScroll to 0 in a document ready binding added _after_ the jquery mobile javascript is included in your document.

Answer (score 2):

This is a known issue that may be refactored in jQuery Mobile 1.1. The issue is that to animate the transition to another page the `viewport` has to be at the top of the page so that the current page and the page transitioning in are vertically lined-up.

If you were half-way down a long list on one page (say `1000px`) and the page you are transferring to is only a few hundred pixels tall then the current page would animate off the screen properly but the new page would not be visible as it would be above the viewport.

I fix this by using [iScroll](http://cubiq.org/iscroll-4) for my scrolling regions. That way all the pages occupy 100% width/height of the viewport and no scrolling-to-the-top-before-transitions will occur.

Comment: Thanks for the answers. We're deliberately avoiding iScroll as it doesn't perform as well as native scrolling. I guess it's either a jumpy interface, or less than ideal scrolling.

Comment: @DonH, we just found a solution. Please see the response.

Answer (score 2):

We've run into this a number of times. Our solution is to ensure all pages are exactly the height of the screen. If your content is longer then a screen, then it goes inside a scrollable DIV container.  If you're targetting iOS 4 and below you'll need a library like iScroll to make the DIV scrollable as overflow: scroll (or auto) don't work properly.
Once you do this you can smoothly transition between pages.

Comment: So, even with jQuery Mobile, iScroll is necessary to have smooth transitions? I thought jQuery Mobile would cover all my mobile UI needs, as expected. Bummer.